# How does glmnet() handle with both penalized and unpenalized covariates?

Tags: lasso, glmnet

Is it possible to do a lasso model with both penalized and un-penalized covariates? That is, I want to do an estimate with `Y ~ gamma * X + beta * Z`, where X is a `n*p` penalized features and Z a `n*q` un-penalized covariates of continues or factor variables.

Answer (score 8):

One way to learn about the functionality of an R package is to look at its documentation.

The command `?glmnet` takes us to the help page for the function. Here, we are presented with a number of options pertaining to the function, and an exhaustive list of the additional arguments one may pass to it.

Of particular interest is this entry:

> `penalty.factor`
>   Separate penalty factors can be applied to each coefficient. This is a number that multiplies lambda to allow differential shrinkage. Can be 0 for some variables, which implies no shrinkage, and that variable is always included in the model. Default is 1 for all variables (and implicitly infinity for variables listed in exclude). Note: the penalty factors are internally rescaled to sum to nvars, and the lambda sequence will reflect this change.